# Python callback functions

Tags: python-3.x

Looking for a simple solution (simpler than the qsort example). I'm using Python 3 and gcc 4.7 on a linux system. I've created a shared library where I can call C functions within that library from Python. I would like to be able to call a function within the C library from Python using a Python callback function as one of the arguments. This way a function from the C library can call another Python function back. I've looked at several examples (qsort example and others) and can't get it to work. Can someone show me a very simple example of how it's done from both the Python side and the C side? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
Python:

```
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.CDLL('sharedlib.so', use_errno=True)

...

CB_FUNC_TYPE = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)

def cb():
    print('Called from C library.')

cb_func = CB_FUNC_TYPE(cb)
mylib.test(cb_func)
```

C:

```
typedef void ( *callback_t )( void );
void test( callback_t cb )
{
    printf("Called from Python.\n");
    cb();
}
```

Of course, if you want return values and arguments, this gets a little more complicated, but not much.